# catch PacketTooBigException() block not works in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

My requirement is to store an image array in db. While storing that image array, Hibernate throws an exception `GenericJDBCException` & lot of stacktrace & then `Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large`. My requirement is to increase packet query size of db when I encounter `PacketTooBigException`. So I had taken two catch blocks of `catch(PacketTooBigException e){...}`  and `catch (Exception e){..}`.

But Hibernate never throws PacketTooBigException directly as like in JDBC. Hibernate first throws `GenericJDBCException` and then `Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException:`. To overcome the scenario, in catch block I had written `if(e.getCause().getClass() == PacketTooBigException.class){..my job..}`.

1) Am I going in right way? 
2) Or anybody can suggest me the better approach so that I can directly catch `PacketTooBigException`.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

As you rightly analyzed hibernate wraps the original databse excption as cause.

The question though is if it makes sense to catch such an exception. I don't know your business domain, but generally PacketTooBigException means you are trying to store a file which is too big as blob.

Such issues are better dealt with at validation time. Either you increase the maximum allowed size by

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = <some big value>
```

and validate while uploading the file.

**Update:**

According to mysql documentation it is safe to increase the limit for all queries (by changing the variable or editing my.ini).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html

Quoting from above link:

> It is safe to increase the value of this variable because the extra
>   memory is allocated only when needed. For example, mysqld allocates
>   more memory only when you issue a long query or when mysqld must
>   return a large result row. The small default value of the variable is
>   a precaution to catch incorrect packets between the client and server
>   and also to ensure that you do not run out of memory by using large
>   packets accidentally.

But even after increasing it to a new max, you always run a risk of uploading a bigger file, so it is always better to have a validation check on user interface itself.

Comment: Thanks @Rangalo, Initial size of max_allowed_packet is 1mb. M Upload'g around 900kb image. But after convert'g it into byte array, its size increases more than 1mb. Hence I am getting exception. Yes, definitely their is way of 'max_allowed_packet'. N i want to set that only when I got 'PacketTooBigException'. Thanks for time Rangalo. Your suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Thank you @Rangalo, yes m doing validation for less than 1mb image file. But internally packet size of query increases to 1196355kb+ for 900kb image. Hence it generates `PacketTooBigException` which I want to catch. Needs your suggestion.

Comment: validate against the converted size or have a considerably large buffer than allowed. 1MB is anyway too low as mentioned in the documentation link.

Comment: Thanks. End user will not accept that he is uploading more than 1mb file, in fact he is uploading a file of 900kb. Is their way to catch `PacketTooBigException`. I done like `if(e.getCause().getClass() == PacketTooBigException.class)` in my exception block. Your suggestions are helpful.